# "Dimensions" options in Data pane

Tags: tableau-api

I am using Tableau Server Version: 2020.2.0 (20202.20.0425.1206) 64-bit Linux

I am trying to use geographic data.

[From a tutorial](https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/maps_howto_simple.htm)

> In the Data pane, under **Dimensions**, double-click State.

[image]

I can't find "Dimensions" options, where is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case Province and Gender are the dimensions - those values above [Measure Names] (which is also a dimension).

Since 2020.2 (as per your comment) it looks like Dimensions and Measures aren't separated with a title. They are separated by the horizontal line and also the colour - with dimensions blue by default and measures green.

Comment: Thank you. I am using Tableau Server Version: 2020.2.0 (20202.20.0425.1206) 64-bit Linux

Comment: edited the answer but it remains basically the same. Looks like a minor interface update with the 2020.2 release